# Does --num-flaky-test-attempts rerun the whole suite or just the failed test?

Tags: firebase-test-lab

The [documentation for `--num-flaky-test-attempts`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--num-flaky-test-attempts) parameter of `gcloud firebase test android run` says the following:

> Specifies the number of times a test execution should be reattempted if one or more of its test cases fail for any reason.

This means it reruns only the failed tests but not the whole suite, right?  In other words, as soon as a test passes it won't be retried, right?

Answer (score 4):

The command line parameter `--num-flaky-test-attempts` of `gcloud firebase test android run` appears to rerun all of the tests instead of just the failed tests.

I ran a suite of tests using `--num-flaky-test-attempts 10` and here timestamps from the logs for one test in the suite:

```
04-27 03:41:51.225 passed
04-27 03:41:50.519 passed
04-27 03:41:43.533 failed
04-27 03:41:48.625 failed 
04-27 03:42:13.886 failed
04-27 03:41:33.749 failed
04-27 03:41:43.694 failed
04-27 03:41:42.101 failed
04-27 03:41:20.310 passed
04-27 03:40:17.819 passed
04-27 03:33:14.154 failed
```

It appears to have executed the entire test suite each time.  In some cases the test mentioned above passed and in some cases it failed.  It passed and failed multiple times, so clearly it's rerunning the test no matter whether it passed or failed.

I believe there were 11 total tests because I specified `--num-flaky-test-attempts 10` which means it attempted to run the suite once and since that failed it ran 10 more times for a total of 11.

Here is the full command in case that's helpful to anyone:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
--project locuslabs-android-sdk \
--app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
--test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
--device model=walleye,version=28,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait \
--test-targets "class com.locuslabs.android.sdk.TestUITest" \
--use-orchestrator \
--num-flaky-test-attempts 10 \
--timeout 30m \
--environment-variables numShards=10,shardIndex=2 \
--verbosity debug
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states the following for `--num-flaky-test-attempts`:

> Specifies the number of times a test execution should be reattempted if one or more of its test cases fail for any reason. An execution that initially fails but succeeds on any reattempt is reported as FLAKY.

I.e. if one test case in a **test execution** fails, Test Lab will re-run the whole **test execution** again. A **test execution** is comprised of running the whole test suite on one device.

Example: You execute your test suite on two devices, lets call them **A** and **B**. The whole test suite succeeds on **A**, but one test case fails on **B**. In this case only the test suite on device **B** will be re-attempted.