# Flaky test report on on TestMatrix completion after Firebase Test Lab run

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, firebase-test-lab

Where is possible to see the list of tests marked as FLAKY from firebase test LAB?

I'm using:

```
functions.testLab.testMatrix().onComplete(testMatrix => {})
```

to receive the TestMatrix object and

```
--num-flaky-test-attempts=int
```

because they say:

```
Specifies the number of times a test execution should be reattempted if one or more of its test cases fail for any reason. An execution that initially fails but succeeds on any reattempt is reported as FLAKY.
```

In the documentation there is this part:
[image]

But there is no reference to the test marked as Flaky.
Where we can see the list of tests flaky?

In the TestMatrix object received as an output on onComplete, there is also no reference for flaky tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does --num-flaky-test-attempts rerun the whole suite or just the failed test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878676/does-num-flaky-test-attempts-rerun-the-whole-suite-or-just-the-failed-test)

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola Is different. 
I know the behavior of --num-flaky-test-attempts=int:
I want to know how to have the list of tests marked as flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, flaky outcome is not reported at the matrix level at this point.
The flaky results are shown in History, Device, and Test Case views.

History view: [image: history view]

Test Case view: [image: test case view]

Device view: [image: device view]